# Problems parsing Atom RSS

Tags: java, android, rss, atom-feed, xmlpullparser

I have this Atom XML with :

```
<content type="xhtml">
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <table cellspacing="0" class="sites-layout-name-one-column sites-layout-hbox">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="sites-layout-tile sites-tile-name-content-1">
                                <div dir="ltr">
                                    <div>HELLO WHHS STUDENTS CONGRADULATIONS TO ALL </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>DONT CLICK THE WWW</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </content>
```

**If the type is not "xhtml"** it is very easy, i simple have to do this, and it works perfectly:

```
if(name.equals("content")){
                parser.next();
                String content=(Html.fromHtml(parser.getText())).toString();
                //System.out.println("content:"+content);
                current.setDescription(content);
                parser.nextTag();
                continue;
            }
```

The problem is when content type is "xhtml", as it contains some divs on it, my parser crashes. I tryed to implement a while bucle that must get all the text content inside all the divs of the content node but i am getting a crash: `04-30 13:42:28.453: W/System.err(8169): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:TEXT HELLO WHHS STUDE...@2:2135 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41e0b6d8)`

This is my code for the "xhtml" problem case:

```
if(name.equals("content")){
                if (parser.getAttributeValue(null, "type").equals("xhtml")){                    
                    String text = "";
                    while( parser.nextTag() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG && !parser.getName().equals("content") ){  
                        String childname=parser.getName();
                        if(childname.equals("div")){                            
                            if(parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.TEXT && parser.getText()!=null){
                                text+=(Html.fromHtml(parser.getText())).toString();
                            }
                            parser.nextTag();
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    current.setDescription(text);
                    parser.nextTag();
                    continue;
                }
}
```

The exception is in this line:

```
while( parser.nextTag() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG && !parser.getName().equals("content") ){
```